# problems with radius when is possible that is equals null

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i'm building a widget for my application layout. I have problems with the radius because when the widget in another file and I don't call the parameters that control the radius, the card disappears. I have insert the function that controll if the radius is null but the card keeps disappearing if the value is null.

Here is the code:

```
    class ContainerCard extends StatelessWidget {
          ContainerCard({
            this.child,
            this.backgroundColor,
            this.alignment,
            this.height,
            this.width,
            this.topLeft,
            this.topRight,
            this.bottomLeft,
            this.bottomRight,
          });
        
          final Widget child;
          final Color backgroundColor;
          final Alignment alignment;
          final double height, width, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Align(
              alignment: alignment == null ? Alignment.center : alignment,
              child: Container(
                height: height,
                width: width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: backgroundColor == null ? Colors.white : backgroundColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: setRadius(topLeft),
                    topRight: setRadius(topRight),
                    bottomLeft: setRadius(bottomLeft),
                    bottomRight: setRadius(bottomRight),
                  ),
                ),
                child: child,
              ),
            );
          }
        
          Radius setRadius(double radius) {
            return Radius.circular(radius) == null
                ? Radius.circular(0)
                : Radius.circular(radius);
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you can set default values to border radius, like this

```
class ContainerCard extends StatelessWidget {
          ContainerCard({
            this.child,
            this.backgroundColor,
            this.alignment,
            this.height,
            this.width,
            this.topLeft = 0,
            this.topRight = 0,
            this.bottomLeft = 0,
            this.bottomRight = 0,
          });
```